# prove that non cyclic group has two cyclic subgroups of different orders

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

**Theorem:**
non cyclic group has two cyclic subgroups of different orders

---

**Note:** If $C\subset G$ is a cyclic subgroup, let $gen(C)$ be the set of generators of $C$. Then $$G=\dot{\cup}_{C \text{ cyclic subgroup of G}}gen(C)$$ is a partition of $G$

**Proof:**
By contrapositive, will show that if $G$ has at most one cyclic subgroup of each order, then $G$ is itself cyclic
$$n=|G|=\sum_{C \text{ cyclic subgroup of G}}|gen(C)|=\sum_{C\subset G \text{ cyclic}}\phi(|C|)=\sum_{G \text{ has a cyclic subgroup of order d}}\phi(d)\leq n$$
This gives 
$$\sum_{G \text{ has a cyclic subgroup of order d}}\phi(d)=n=\sum_{d|n,d\geq1}\phi(d)$$
Thus for every $d$ of $n$ $(d\geq1)$ there is a cyclic subgroup $C$ of $G$ of order $d$. Taking $d=n$, we say that $G$ contains a cyclic subgroup $C$ of order $n$ thus $G=C$ is cyclic.

---

**Questions:**
Here we are talking about $G$ in general (not necessarily cyclic) but why is $G$ still a disjoint union of generator of cyclic subgroups? How to prove this? How does this lead to $\sum_{G \text{ has a cyclic subgroup of order d}}\phi(d)$ and why is it no larger than $n$? And how it goes from the equality of the sums to "for every $d$ of $n$ $(d\geq1)$ there is a cyclic subgroup $C$ of $G$ of order $d$"

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to say non-trivial cyclic subgroups? If you didn't, then every group has a cyclic subgroup of order $\geq 1$ (Just take any element $g\neq e$ and let it generate a subgroup) and has the trivial subgroup which has order $1$.

If you did mean to say non-trivial subgroups, then your statement is false. Take the Klein four group. This isn't cyclic but all its non-trivial cyclic subgroups have the same order (2).

Comment: But is this sufficient to say that it forms a partition? How about the other two questions?

Comment: Is what sufficient to say it forms a partition?